# merge javascript objects with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have 2 objects:

Object A

```
{
    key1 : 'key1',
    key2 : 'key2'
}
```

Object B

```
{
    key1 : 'override a'
}
```

And I want to merge them like this:

result

```
{
    key1 : 'override a',
    key2 : 'key2'
}
```

Has anybody got a suggestion how to do this in TypeScript (or plain JS)

Comment: `{ ...A, ...B }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Use your favourite search engine with "merge javascript objects with Typescript?" and you would have found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can be leveraged to merge `objects`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const A = {key1 : 'key1', key2 : 'key2'}
const B = {key1 : 'override a'}

// Assign.
const merge = (...args) => Object.assign({}, ...args)

// Output.
const output = merge(A, B)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Comment: It's not on the prototype.

Comment: Also, this modifies `A` so maybe `Object.assign({}, A, B)` would be better, depending on circumstances.

Comment: Defs mate. Thanks for the help 

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method:

```
var merged = Object.assign({}, objectA, objectB);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objectA={key1:1}
var objectB={key1:2,key2:3};
//create new object and merge the two object which will not affect the original object

var newObject = Object.assign({}, objectA, objectB);
console.log(newObject);
//merging in the original object
Object.assign(objectA,objectB);
console.log(objectA);
```

Answer (score -1):

`const c: any = {...a,...b};`

b should override a or provide an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "shout conflict"?

Answer (score -1):

Using spread

```js
const a = {key1 : 'key1', key2 : 'key2'}
const b = {key1 : 'override a'}

console.log({ ...a, ...b })
```